# How to tell flake8 to ignore comments

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I'm using flake8 in emacs in order to clean up my python code. I find it annoying to have my comments flagged as errors (`E501 line too long (x > 79 characters)`). I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to kindly ask flake8 to ignore comments, both single and multi-line, but still let me know when my non-comment lines are too long?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can tell to ignore E501 error, but I don't think it will able to distinguish between code and comments.

Comment: Only for that specific error, or for all errors? What do with a line that contains both code and comment? (i.e. `a = 4 # a is four`)?

Comment: In that case, I would want it to be flagged. I just want it to ignore pure comment lines if possible.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I've figured out a possible solution to this, but there might be something better. If you write a comment that will raise an E501 error, i.e. it is too long, you can append that line with `# noqa: E501`, and flake8 will ignore it. For example:

`# This is a really really long comment that would usually be flagged by flake8 because it is longer than 79 characters`

would usually raise an E501, but

`# This is a really really long comment that would usually be flagged by flake8 because it is longer than 79 characters  # noqa: E501`

will not.

documented [here](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when there's a line that's too long in a multi-line docstring, is there a different syntax for that ?

Comment: Doesn’t work for Sphinx comments (e.g. `#: Sphinx comment`) because that `# noqa: E501` will be emitted as part of the documentation.

Comment: `# too long comment line  # noqa: E501` approach works, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

You can change the list of codes ignored by `flake8` using a [configuration file](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html). For example, in your project directory create a file named `.flake8` with the following content:

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    # line too long
    path/to/file.py: E501,
```

This may be easier than using `# noqa` comments.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP because it also suppresses E501 on non-comment lines

Comment: @leoll2 That's a valid point, although Google shows this as the top result for getting flake8 to ignore line length - so it could be helpful for many visitors. Hopefully LLMs will improve search results in the future...

Comment: This got me what I needed, but I used *:<my-annoying-error-code> to silence the error in all files

Comment: If you want to ignore an error in all files you don't need to use the wildcard, you can just do `ignore=E501` and that will apply to all files.  You only need `per-file-ignores` if you want to only ignore it in specific files.

Answer (score 20):

Using an inline comment `# noqa: E501` should ignore this issue for you.

**If you have a multi-line comment**, you can ignore inline *at the end of the multi-line string* like so:

```
def do_something():
    """
    Long url as a reference.

    References:
        1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling
    """  # noqa: E501
    ...
```

**If you have a long inline comment**, you can ignore by marking the comment with `# noqa: E501` the same way:

```py
# Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling  # noqa: E501
```

^ Weirdly enough, you need to add the 2nd `#` for it to work...

Comment: your reply is better as it mentions how to support multi-line comment.