# How to ignore flake8 "line too long" errors in a heredoc

Tags: python, flake8

Suppose I have a file with a heredoc with long lines:

```
    some_string = '''
very long lines here, 20 lines each of length 500
'''
```

How do I ignore all the flake8 "line too long" errors in that heredoc, without excluding the entire file from checking?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876079/how-to-tell-flake8-to-ignore-comments) describes `# noqa` for a single line, but I can't put that in the heredoc.  [The manual](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html) does not seem to describe ignoring a chunk of code.

Comment: Why do you have such long lines in the first place? Is it possible you could put them in a separate txt file instead?

Comment: Could, but for a unit test, it's much more readable to just have the example right there. It's not actually length 500, it's more like 100. I just didn't want people to tell me to fiddle with the line length.

Answer (score 31):

Oh oops, I found the answer.  I can put `# noqa` at the end of the heredoc:

```
    some_string = '''
very long lines here, 20 lines each of length 500
'''  # noqa
```

I feel silly.

Comment: pls don't feel silly, you helped me today :)

Comment: @hintze Ha ha, great!

Comment: What is the long line is comment?

Comment: @xliiv I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean

"What **if** the long line is a comment?"

But after second try it turned out it works like expected (put `  # noqa` at the end of long comment), so nevermind.