# In VS Code, how can I change the problem level of a certain error/violation from the Flake8 extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

I'm using VS Code with Flake8 configured to check some obvious issues for my Python code. However, some of its errors are not really errors in my current development phase, e.g. `E501` (line too long) and `F401` (unused import).

The annoying thing is that the relevant lines are marked in red, which makes more serious errors non-obvious.

Is there a way I can tell Flake8 to treat them as warnings instead of errors?

I searched all over, but only discovered ways to either ignore the check all together, or explicitly mark one line as ignored, e.g. [How to tell flake8 to ignore comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876079/how-to-tell-flake8-to-ignore-comments). They are not what I need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `flake8.severity` setting contributed by the Flake8 extension. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-flake8#settings.

Quoting from the docs, the default value is:

> ```json
> {
>   "convention": "Information",
>   "error": "Error",
>   "fatal": "Error",
>   "refactor": "Hint",
>   "warning": "Warning",
>   "info": "Information"
> }
> ```

The description in the docs is:

> Controls mapping of severity from flake8 to VS Code severity when displaying in the problems window. You can override specific flake8 error codes
>
> ```json
> {
>   "convention": "Information",
>   "error": "Error",
>   "fatal": "Error",
>   "refactor": "Hint",
>   "warning": "Warning",
>   "W0611": "Error",
>   "undefined-variable": "Warning"
> }
> ```

Pay particular attention to the property `W0611` in that example above. See also https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html.

Since Flake8 uses other plugins, you'll need to refer to the readmes and docs of those plugins to find out what error codes they provide (I think Flake8 mostly just uses them without any sort of translation):

- https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes
- https://github.com/pycqa/mccabe

Comment: is this AI generated? the info here isn't really relevant and the links are all wrong

Comment: @anthonysottile not AI generated (that would be quite hypocritical of me, considering that I'm one of the primary users flagging AI-generated content right now). One link is wrong by accident. Thanks for bringing that up. I've fixed that now. I'm not sure what you mean by "isn't really relevant". AFAIK, this is exactly the right VS Code Flake8 setting to use for what's being asked here.

Comment: well for one W0611 and undefined-variable are pylint codes

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, at least for VS Code. Tips for others: VS Code provides a graphical interface to change these settings, for that flake8 extension. (In fact, I didn't find out where and how to change the configuration file directly, but doesn't matter as of the graphical interface.)

Comment: @anthonysottile I'm just quoting from the Flake8 VS Code extension docs. see https://pypi.org/project/flake8-pylint/, for example of how that could be legit

Comment: flake8 doesn't support 4 digit numbered codes

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`tox.ini` or `.flake8`](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html) file in your project, and add your exceptions there. Flake8 should pick up on that.

From those docs:

```
[flake8]
# it's not a bug that we aren't using all of hacking, ignore:
# H101: Use TODO(NAME)
# H202: assertRaises Exception too broad
# H233: Python 3.x incompatible use of print operator
# H301: one import per line
# H306: imports not in alphabetical order (time, os)
# H401: docstring should not start with a space
# H403: multi line docstrings should end on a new line
# H404: multi line docstring should start without a leading new line
# H405: multi line docstring summary not separated with an empty line
# H501: Do not use self.__dict__ for string formatting
extend-ignore = H101,H202,H233,H301,H306,H401,H403,H404,H405,H501
```

And now Flake8, and thus VS Code, won't flag any of those.

Comment: would be nice if you spelled out what the file contents might look like to me. It's not clear to me what should go in there.

Comment: I don't think these solve my issue, as this only allows me to "ignore" a lint hint completely. What I need is to change their severity. The other answer does provide a way for VS Code at least. Thanks anyway.

Comment: like it or not, cherry-picking info for right now is... kind of the point of SO. That's why we [don't allow answers that are just links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587) (which by the way, I'm not saying this answer is that, but I'm saying it would be nice if you expanded). And the question isn't about _ignoring_ errors. It's about "_demoting_" the way they appear in VS Code into warnings instead errors.

Comment: @renyuneyun that's kind of the point of linting though: either your code doesn't match the required style, or it does. There's no in between when it comes to matching a code formatting style guide. Your code's either following it, and there is nothing to flag, or it's not, and that's an error that will "break" your CI/testing/etc. to prevent any changes from being made that don't match the project's code style. (but _won't_ prevent your code from running. They're only style errors that you need to fix, not _actual_ errors that break the Python parser)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, your point is valid only for Golang-style languages -- there is an official-forced style standard, and custom standards are not allowed. Maybe I'm not old enough, but I can remind you that before this, each language (e.g. C, C++, Java) has many different styles, and thus lint tools should be flexible enough to cope with that. I do not know if Python belongs to Golang-style, but at least that is not a requirement for "lint" in general. Let aside the difference between an Error and a Warning -- GCC allows customization of that as well.

Comment: Except we're not talking about any of those for this question. We're talking about Python. Which _famously_ has so much style guiding that white space is semantic. It's why flake8 has an 8 in it: it automates [the official PEP8 Python Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) requirements.